# data() is not a function for querying firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to figure out how to query a Firebase database for a while, but to no avail. Here's what I have right now:

```js
async query(){
    const bar = firebase.firestore().collection('foo');
    const res = await bar.orderBy('gopher').limit(20).get();
}
```

`res` isn't the actual data, but rather some sort of internal object:

```js
{
    o_: {
        J_ : {
             fromCache: false,
             ne: true,
             ...
        }
    },
    q_ : {
         ...
    }
}
```

For the data structure, I have a collection called `foo`, and multiple documents with unique ids - which each have a numerical field called `gopher`. I'm trying to sort by `gopher` and get 20 documents at the top, but `res.data()` is not a function and `res.data` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) type object.  If you want to see the results of the query, you can get the raw data using the pattern described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).  I've renamed the variables to be more descriptive.

```
const fooCollection = firebase.firestore().collection('foo');
const querySnapshot = await fooCollection.orderBy('gopher').limit(20).get();
if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
}
else {
    console.log("No documents in the results");
}
```

Comment: `querySnapshot.size`, not `querySnapshot.size()`, but other than that, it works great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be `res.docs` not `res.data`

`res.docs` contains array firestore document snapshot.

*To print all the data*

```
console.log(res.docs.map(snap=>snap.data()));
```

Comment: `res.docs` still returns the same weird internal firestore object. Not the actual data itself. But it does return 20.

Comment: returns false. Like I said, it still returns an array of 20 objects in an array, just weird internal stuff like `{o_, j_}...`

Comment: I got this , array contain firestore documents which then can be accessed with data() method. For eg. First record will br res.docs[0].data()

Comment: Nope, `res.docs.data()` is not a function and `res.docs.data` is undefined.

Comment: You have to access like this `res.docs[0].data();`